# How much time is needed for bruteforce kerberos/ntlm?

Tags: brute-force, kerberos

How much time does an attacker need for full bruteforce on typical complexity password policy given either:

- kerberos ticket/ as req or
- Ntlm transaction

This depends on the algorithm used (rc4/aes). 
Assuming a typical proprietary hardware.